# Possible values of $\gcd(x^2, y^3)$ when $\gcd(x,y)=6$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $x$ and $y$ be positive integers and let $\gcd(x,y)=6$. How do we find all the values for $\gcd(x^2,y^3)$? How can we show that these are the only possibilities?

Answer (score 7):

Hint:

If $gcd(x,y)=5$, then one of $x$ or $y$ has a single 5 in its prime factorisation and the other has one or more 5s.  They have no other prime factors in common.

So $x^2$ must have at least two 5s and $y^3$ at least three 5s.  But either $x^2$ has no more than two 5s or $y^3$ has no more than three 5s. So $gcd(x^2,y^3)$ is either $5^2=25$ or $5^3=125$.

In your problem you have 6 not 5, which makes the problem twice as complicated.  See what you can do.

Comment: We would need to split up the 6 into primes, 2 and 3. So does this mean that one of $x$ or $y$ must have a single 2 and 3 in its prime factorization and the other must have one or more 2's and 3's?

Comment: @johnnymath: yes but the statements for 2s and 3s are separate.  Look for example at $x=60$ and $y=54$.

Comment: OK now I see that $gcd(60,54)=6$. 60 can be factored into $2^2*3*5$ and 54 can be factored into $2*3^3$. So the GCD equals the multiplication of the smallest powers of each of the factors. So one of $x$ or $y$ must have one power of 2 while the other has more, and one must have one power of 3 while the other has more. So then would we have to apply the above argument to both 2 and 3?